# Why is my buffer stored in two locations in stack?

Tags: c

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buf[512];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
gcc -g -z execstack buf.c -o buf -fno-stack-protector
```

**Question:**

So Basically using `gdb` I set a breakpoint on line `return 0;` and run the script as follow: `run $(python -c 'print "A"*600')`, and then when I do `x/600x $rsp`, I get my buffer start at:

```
0x7fffffffdcf0: 0xffffdfe8      0x00007fff      0xf7fd3298      0x00000002
0x7fffffffdd00: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffdd10: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141

// it goes on... until
0x7fffffffdf50: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

But then when I go further down the stack, I also see:

```
0x7fffffffe2f0: 0x776f6c66      0x6675622f      0x41414100      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe300: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141

// It goes until
0x7fffffffe540: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe550: 0x48530041      0x3d4c4c45      0x6e69622f      0x7361622f
```

Also for buffer overflow exploit, If I use first location, my exploit doesn't work, but if I use second location it works.

So May I know why is my buffer stored in two different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buffer isn’t stored in two places. You’re just copying the data yourself in your code. There’s the input that’s given to `main` and then your buffer where you copy the input. That’s two copies of it but only one is your buffer.

Using gdb to show where `argv[1]` is stored will also show this:

```
p argv[1]
$1 = 0x7ffffffee2ce 'A' <repeats 600 times>
```

The address will of course be different on different systems.

Comment: you mean first is `argv[1]` and the second is my `buf`?

Comment: @amiTheregroot Yes, exactly

Comment: So after `strcpy()` I did `argv[1] = '\0'; printf("%s\n\n\n\n%s\n",buf, argv[1]);`. the output is `AAAAAAAAAA...` and `(null)` for `argv[1]`, but the stack still looks the same. if you wanna confirm, you can try it.

Comment: @amiTheregroot Which is expected since you changed `argv[1]` to point to null, not its contents. Change `argv[1][0]` instead of it allows.

Comment: I did that too, same result.

Comment: I don't think the standard requires the memory argv[n] points to to be mutable.

Comment: @Swordfish then why does my `printf(argv[1])` prints it as `(null)`?

Comment: @amiTheregroot It will only print (null) if you change the *pointer*, not the *contents*. If you change the contents it will print nothing since it's an empty string.

Comment: But you can easily just do `p argv[1]` in gdb and it'll tell you where that points to. It points to the area where the second copy of the data is, for me: $2 = 0x7ffffffee2ce 'A' <repeats 15 times>. And if I try to change `argv[1][0]` I get: $1 = 0x7ffffffee2ce "B", 'A' <repeats 14 times>

Comment: okay, so I did little something, `printf("%p", argv[1])` and the address is the lower part of the stack containing `AAAAA(s)`.

Comment: @samikuhmonen fyi: `No symbol "argv" in current context.` for `p argv[1]`.